# AOT in angular 5 without using CLI

Tags: angular5, angular-aot

Before Angular 5 release I could configure AOT by following official doc https://angular.io/guide/aot-compiler

I understand that official documentation switched the focus to CLI. Is there any structured guide about Angular 5 AOT without using CLI?

(I've seen this link https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/19339#issuecomment-332607471)

Comment: I just stumbled across this article while wondering about the same thing: https://blog.angularindepth.com/setting-up-angular-from-scratch-1f518c65d8ab

Comment: Hi Bob, that article explains how to start Angular app with minimal dependencies but nothing about how to configure AOT.

Comment: Oh I'm sorry your right. Here is guide to setup aot not using the cli. @ngtools/webpack: https://medium.com/ag-grid/webpack-tutorial-understanding-ngtools-webpack-306dd7f9e07d